# Auth0 SPA TypeError: Cannot read property 'idTokenPayload' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, auth0

I’m getting an error on my Gatsby+Auth0 app when trying to log in. Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idTokenPayload' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/utils/auth.js:1
> 1 | import auth0 from "auth0-js"
  2 | import { navigate } from "gatsby"
  3 | 
  4 | const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"
```

When I log in to my app it works the first time and I can see that authResult is console logging proper values, but the moment I click on any routes or refresh the page, it returns this error. I was working fine until this morning, I didn’t change anything other than some CSS styles.

Here is my auth.js file:

```
import auth0 from "auth0-js"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"

const auth = isBrowser
  ? new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID,
      redirectUri: process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK,
      responseType: "token id_token",
      scope: "openid profile email",
    })
  : {}

const tokens = {
  accessToken: false,
  idToken: false,
  expiresAt: false,
}

let user = {}

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  if (!isBrowser) {
    return
  }

  return localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true"
}

export const login = () => {
  if (!isBrowser) {
    return
  }

  auth.authorize()
}

const setSession = (cb = () => {}) => (err, authResult) => {

  console.log(authResult);

  localStorage.setItem("userAuthID", authResult.idTokenPayload.sub)
  localStorage.setItem("userIdToken", 'Bearer '+authResult.idToken)
  if (err) {
    navigate("/")
    cb()
    return
  }

  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    let expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
    tokens.accessToken = authResult.accessToken
    tokens.idToken = authResult.idToken
    tokens.expiresAt = expiresAt
    user = authResult.idTokenPayload
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true)
    navigate("/account")
    cb()
  }

}

export const silentAuth = callback => {
  if (!isAuthenticated()) return callback()
  auth.checkSession({}, setSession(callback))
}

export const handleAuthentication = () => {
  if (!isBrowser) {
    return
  }

  auth.parseHash(setSession())
}

export const getProfile = () => {
  return user
}

export const logout = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", false)
  localStorage.removeItem("userIdToken");
  auth.logout()
}
```

And here is my callback.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { handleAuthentication } from "../utils/auth"
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

export default class callback extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    handleAuthentication();
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate('/account')
    }, 1500);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="hero is-white is-fullheight">
          <div className="hero-body">
            <div className="container">
              <h1 className="title is-1 is-spaced has-text-centered logo-text">Fottom</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Can some please help me find what is missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are trying to access the property `idTokenPayload` of `authResult`, without checking before if `authResult` is null. In your `setSession()` function, in case of error, you are accessing `authResult`. You should only set the localStorage items when the login was successful.

Try this code:

```js
const setSession = (cb = () => {}) => (err, authResult) => {

  console.log(authResult);

  if (err) {
    navigate("/")
    cb()
    return
  }

  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {

    localStorage.setItem("userAuthID", authResult.idTokenPayload.sub) // moved after error control
    localStorage.setItem("userIdToken", 'Bearer '+authResult.idToken) // moved after error control

    let expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
    tokens.accessToken = authResult.accessToken
    tokens.idToken = authResult.idToken
    tokens.expiresAt = expiresAt
    user = authResult.idTokenPayload
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true)
    navigate("/account")
    cb()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mhSangar that you should probably only attempt to access the payload AFTER ensuring that it's not `null`.

But I think there's also another layer to the issue that you're experiencing. You mentioned that everything works fine until you refresh, which I'm assuming is when the token refresh is attempted. My guess is that the issue lies within the `checkSession` method.

Currently, it's being invoked like this:

`auth.checkSession({}, setSession(callback))`

You have to pass a config as the first argument to that method (not just an empty object). When I invoke it in my app, I pass the following args:

```js
{
  audience,
  callbackURL,
  clientID,
  domain
}
```

Try passing those arguments to `auth.checkSession` and see if that fixes it.

i.e.

```js
export const silentAuth = callback => {
  if (!isAuthenticated()) return callback()
  auth.checkSession(
    {
      domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID,
      redirectUri: process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK,
      audience: YOUR_AUDIENCE (looks like AUTH0_DOMAIN/api/v2/)
    },
    setSession(callback)
  )
}
```